# spurious hardware memory 'errors' on hp dl380 g5's being generated

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, hp-proliant

i've got 2 new HP dl380g5 servers running HP's esxi4 patched to 219382. they have both been patched up to the latest hp firmware levels (firmware cd 8.7)

both are running 32gb (4 x 8gb sticks)

both servers are showing the same symptoms - the memory lights come on for two (random) dimms on the front of the server and the health led turns red. sometimes the server stays up and running with no problems. othertimes the server locks dead and only a power reset can bring it back.

there is nothing showing in the ilo logs and nothing within the vmware hardware monitoring. the memory has been replaced

i've got other customers that have been running dl380g5's with out any issues on esx3.5 - this is our first vsphere deployment with them.

these are meant to go live soon so any advice would be great.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things;

You say they're new but G5's are an old model, did you buy them second-hand? also is the memory HP-branded or second-market? was it replaced with HP-memory?

Also you're on SmartStart 8.7 but what system firmware (BIOS) are you on, the latest for the G5 is '2009.07.10 10 Sep 2009', also is your iLO at 1.78?

Have you logged it with HP?

It's odd that it's happening on two machines, we've certainly found 380G5's to be stable too.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar problems on DL380 G5 - memory lights on, presumably indicating a memory error, but luckily no other symptoms.

On one of the machines we took it out of the vSphere cluster and ran memory check MemTest86 - this didn`t reveal any issues, although the orange light returned. When checked a few days later the light was off again and hasn't been seen on again in the past month.

We've just had another similar machine show the memory light on for one of the HP DIMMs (in 8x4GB config). Will let you know how we get on investigating this. As we haven't seen any other symptoms, it isn't high on our priorities, so may be a while!